# How to replace every '-' into space ' ' . Function .replace('-',' ',regex=True) is not working on this case

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, replace

Unable to convert every '-' into blank space.

```py
dataset = ['0000sh--_dsd' , '0000sd---_dsd' , '000ad-_512']
test1 = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
```

I tried this
`test1.replace('-',' ',regex=True)

Input: 0000sh--_dsd

I need this as Output:  0000sh  _dsd (which is not happening)

Python is not allowing to convert to space. Please advise how to sort out this situation.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I realised to late it's a dataframe
In this case I would just solve it like this

```
dataset = ['0000sh--_dsd', '0000sd---_dsd', '000ad-_512']
dataset = [line.replace("-", "") for line in dataset]
test1 = pd.DataFrame(dataset)
```

Ignore my first answer below

---

Strings in Python are immutable so you need to use this

```
test1 = test1.replace('-', '')
```